# How to find the last value in a row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

I need to collect the rightmost values in one column, the last values in a row from a table, see Example.
This is a table of changes in commodity prices over time.
It is necessary to display the last price for the goods in a separate column.
Solutions are welcomed by both array formula and Apps script.

[image: Example]

Tried the HLOOKUP(99999,F2:J2,TRUE) function
Line by line works, unstable in ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP(99999,F2:J5,TRUE))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one more approach:

```
=byrow(F2:J,lambda(Σ,iferror(choosecols(torow(Σ,1),-1))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of the last column.

In this case, how about the following sample formula and script?

#### Sample formula:

```
=BYROW(A2:I10,LAMBDA(x,LET(ARRAY,SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,x),","),LENGTH,COUNTA(ARRAY),IFERROR(INDEX(ARRAY,1,LENGTH)))))
```

#### Sample script:

In this sample, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE(A2:I10)` into a cell.

```js
const SAMPLE = values => values.map(r => [r.filter(String).pop()]);
```

If your Spreadsheet is large, I'm worried that the custom function might not be able to be used. In that case, please test the following sample script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set your destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const values = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName).getDataRange().getValues();
  const res = values.map(r => [r.filter(String).pop()]);
  ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName).getRange(1, 1, res.length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Testing:

When the above formula and script are used, the following result is obtained. Cells "A12" and "B12" have the formula and the custom function, respectively.

[image]

#### References:

- [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930)
- [LET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)